# Keep backslashes when passing path param in bash from powershell

Tags: windows, bash, powershell, path-separator

I have a powershell .ps1 script where I am calling a ./configure script like this:

```
bash ./configure --prefix="$my_path"
```

my_path variable is some dynamic path like C:\jenkins\mydir\84534yfiybsdl\Temp that becomes C:jenkinsmydir84534yfiybsdlTemp in ./configure script and I believe I'd need to pass "C:\/jenkins\/mydir\/84534yfiybsdl\/Temp" for it to work.

I tried to use -replace '\', '/' earlier in powershell before calling the script,
and --prefix="${my_path////\/}" and even --prefix="$(my_path)" but nothing worked.
Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing your path with `/` rather than `\` as the path separator may work:

```
bash ./configure --prefix="$($my_path.Replace('\', '/'))"
```

If `\` must be used, escape them as `\\`:

```
bash ./configure --prefix="$($my_path.Replace('\', '\\'))"
```

*Assuming you're using **WSL***, you could **avoid the problem altogether** if you **call via `wsl -e`** as follows:

```
wsl -e bash ./configure --prefix=$my_path
```

Note: `-e` is short for `--exec`; the [`wsl.exe` overview page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands) is currently limited to documenting CLI options related to distro management; use `wsl --help` to see all options.

---

The **original problem is caused by the - now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/basic-commands#deprecated-wsl-commands) - `bash.exe` WSL CLI *inappropriately* parsing its arguments as if they had been provided from *inside* a Bash session**, causing undesired interpretation of what should be *verbatim* arguments:

- Notably, verbatim `\` characters unexpectedly become *escape* characters, which breaks arguments that contain (unescape) Windows path strings, and `$`-prefixed arguments are expanded *up front*.
- When calling via `wsl -e`, no such undesired interpretation occurs.

**Example**:

The following uses an ad-hoc bash script to echo the first argument it is given (the last argument on the command line, `a\b`):

- Calling via `wsl -e` passes the arguments through verbatim:

  ```
  # OK: -> 'a\b'
  wsl.exe -e bash -c 'printf %s $1' - a\b
  ```
- To counteract the undesired up-front interpretation performed by `bash.exe`, you must unexpectedly escape both the `$` and `\` characters:

  ```
  # !! Unexpected need to \-escape $ and \ to get output 'a\b'
  bash.exe -c 'printf %s \$1' - a\\b
  ```

Comment: Thank you so so much! Simply passing --prefix="$($my_path.Replace('\', '/'))" worked! Wish I'd asked earlier:)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @Marisol. If you're using WSL, the `wsl -e ...` solution may ultimately be preferable, because you then don't have to worry about escaping / transforming individual arguments.